# How do I create a buffer overflow to test Address Sanitizer?

Tags: swift, buffer-overflow, address-sanitizer

**Problem**

I'm attempting to create a buffer overflow in order to learn more about Address Sanitizer. I've written the following code which I *thought* would create a buffer overflow, though I must be mistaken as it's not throwing the expected `"Heap buffer overflow detected"`.

**Attempt**

```
    var ints : [UInt8] = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]

    let a = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: &ints, count: ints.count)

    a[28] = 17 // array out of index
```

I've enabled Address Sanitizer in Xcode by clicking my application > Edit Scheme... and then "Enable Address Sanitizer". Then I rebuilt my application before running.

### Question

How do I create a buffer overflow in Swift 2?

Comment: `a` is not used at all. Did you mean `a[28] = 17` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-413/?time=947

> Address Sanitizer is an LLVM tool for C-based languages.

and https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-413/?time=1422

> In order to use Address Sanitizer, Xcode passes a special flag to clang.

It seems that the Address Sanitizer is only available with `clang`
for C, Objective-C etc., but not with the Swift compiler `swiftc`.

A simple C program which triggers a buffer overflow is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int *p = malloc(4 * sizeof(int));
    p[28] = 17;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I set up a bridging header and called it from swift this should still trigger the address sanitizer I assume?

Comment: @DanBeaulieu: Yes, it does.